# Using ref in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to create a schema that has rows reference columns via the columns id attribute. The following xml and xsd will not validate because the column cannot be found

How do I create the schema for the following XML so that i can reference column id from row element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<mapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <rows>
        <row>
            <column id="123" />
            <column id="124" />
        </row>
        <row>
            <column id="123" />
            <column id="124" />
        </row>
    </rows>

    <columns>
        <column id="123">
            <name>Apple</name>
        </column>

        <column id="124">
            <name>Banana</name>
        </column>
    </columns>

</mapping>
```

My xsd looks like this but it doesn't work ... it cannot find the column reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="mapping">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="rows" type="Rows" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="columns"  type="Columns" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>      
    <xsd:key name="PKeyColumn">
        <xsd:selector xpath="columns/column"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>      
    <xsd:keyref name="FKeyColumn" refer="PKeyColumn">
        <xsd:selector xpath="rows/row/column"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:keyref>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="Row">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="column">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xsd:integer" />
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Rows">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="row" type="Row" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:unique name="UKeyColumn">
                <xsd:selector xpath="column"/>
                <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
            </xsd:unique>   
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>  

<xsd:complexType name="Columns">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="column" type="Column" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Column">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer" />
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Can you show the schema you have written so far?

Comment: I added it to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema has a few minor issues - the `element ref="column"` in the `Row` type needs to be `name` instead of `ref`, and it needs a `maxOccurs` larger than 1 (the default).

```
<xsd:complexType name="Row">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="column" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

Once I fix these errors, it all validates fine, and the cross-reference requirement (that every column ID mentioned in a `row` must correspond to one in the `columns` section) is catered for by the `key` and `keyref`.

Comment: But i want to use ref to enforce the idea it is a reference to column. Isnt that whats it for?

Comment: @user3319681 no, `ref` is used to point to a top-level `element` declaration from elsewhere in the schema.  The `key` and `keyref` pair is what enforces the cross-reference constraint, and that is correct already.  If I change one of the "124" references to a "125" I get a validation failure.

Comment: Are you then saying that, given my original intent, the schema as I have it (except for the "ref") is the correct approach?

Comment: @user3319681 yes.  The `unique` inside the `Rows` type ensures that you can't refer to the same column twice in the same row, the `key` asserts that all the column IDs within the `columns` section must be distinct, and the `keyref` handles the cross reference requirement (every `column` in a `row` must match one of the ones in `columns`).

Comment: Thanks for confirming